# Group order items in drupal commerce cart

Tags: commerce

When I add the same product twice to cart:

- **actually:** there is 2 separate orders (1x Chocolate cake $3)
- **expected:** one solid order - 2x Chocolate cake $6

How to make the cart to dispay grouped orders?
thx.